# Android - Why is onAttach() and onCreate() being called after popping backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

**Transition: Fragment A > Fragment B**

Fragment A goes through `onDestroyView()` and does NOT go through any other tear down methods.

**Transition: Fragment B is popped and Fragment A is restored**

Fragment A goes through `onAttach()` and `onCreate()`. Why is this the case? Shouldn't Fragment A only have to recreate its view?

**How fragments are being replaced (in Kotlin):**

```
private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, @IdRes frameId: Int, fragmentTag: String) {
    val transaction: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(frameId, fragment, fragmentTag)
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

**Popping the backstack this way:**

`supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()`

Answer (score 0):

The `FragmentTransaction.replace()` function make this. You need to instantiate your fragment, and use a solution, like ViewPager, to navigate in your fragments. The code in Java or Kotlin make the same thing. I just reply a question similar with your. Try look this: [Change fragments without recreate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923560/change-fragments-without-recreate-them)